# It does not fetch data inside onAppear

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have api links that are inside the api link

I have this class and I fetched the data from it so that it gives me the API links

```
class Api : ObservableObject{

@Published var modelApiLink : [model] = []

func getDataModelApi () {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: APIgetURL.demo) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let token = "38|Xxxxxxx"
    
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, err in
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let dataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.modelApiLink = dataModel
                
            }

        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
}
```

It's ready now
And I made another function to fetch the API data from the previous one

```
@Published var models : [model] = []
    func getData (url : String) {

// Exactly the same as func last, but needs to put a link
}
```

And here I presented the data and its work in onAppear
But it does not give any data

```
struct VideoViewAll : View {

@StateObject var model = Api()
@StateObject var modelApiLink = Api()

‏    var body: some View {
        
‏        VStack {
‏            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
‏                
‏                

ForEach(model.models) { item in
‏                    HStack {
‏                        NavigationLink(destination: detiles(model: item)) {
‏                            Spacer()
‏                            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 15) {

 Text(item.title)
‏                            }.padding(.trailing, 5)
                }
            }
        }
‏        .onAppear() {

‏            modelApiLink.getDataModelApi()
        
‏            for itemModel in modelApiLink.models {

‏                model.getData(url: itemModel.url)

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is not the way how `ObservableObject` works. When you update a `@Published` property the class tells the view to refresh and you can access the updated property.   By the way what is `modelsDemo`? And it makes no sense to create two instances of the same view model.

Comment: By mistake, I did not modify it, it has been modified now

Comment: This way, I can get one direct link from it But when I want to fetch a link from the api, the links don't work

Comment: Can you tell me the right way, I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution